# Pull text from .txt file and display php

Tags: php, html, canvas

I am trying to create some canvases which pulls some text from a .txt file. My .txt contains on every line name, surname, gender and role separated by space. I want to create a new canvas for each row from my .txt file.
This is how i thought to extract the values from my file:

```
$source = fopen('datas.txt', 'r') or die("Problem open file");
while (($data = fgets($source, 1000, " ")) !== FALSE)
{
    $name = $data[0];
    $surname = $data[1];
    $gender = $data[2];
    $role = $data[3];

}
fclose($source);
```

But i don't really know how to put them in a canvas. Can i make a loop or something to create a canvas for each row? I want some suggestions if someone can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by canvas?

Comment: You're already running a loop with the while, so use that and just echo the HTML using `echo "html code";` and `".$variable."; ` if you mean the html element canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the data with a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function canvasSmth( i ) {  
     var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
     var drawtext = canvas.getContext('2d');
     drawtext.font = "30px Arial";
     drawtext.fillText(i,10,50);
}
</script>

$source = fopen('datas.txt', 'r') or die("Problem open file");
while (($data = fgets($source, 1000, " ")) !== FALSE)
{
    $name = $data[0];
    $surname = $data[1];
    $gender = $data[2];
    $role = $data[3];
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> canvasSmth( <?php echo $name ; ?> )'; 
}
fclose($source);
```

Comment: quick question do i include the script part in my php file or in my html code?

Comment: @MihaCraescu In the html code .The spellcheck didn't let me separate the function from the php code to look more clear for some reason .

Comment: thanks for your response. i'm going to try something new to extract the words because my code doesn't work.

Comment: sorry to bother you again..in this line `echo '<script type="text/javascript"> canvasSmth( <?php echo $name ; ?> );` you opened a ' but didn't close it. i have to close it before the last ; right? i'm still trying to make this thing work